# Retrieve the numeric value

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Hello guys i would like to know how to retrieve the value of 47 in this url by jquery so that i can use this value to display the specific records associated with the id

```
...../Rate.aspx#/HotelMobileBooking/Room.aspx?RT=47
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a regular expression for it. `/Room\.aspx\?RT=(\d+)/` does the job:

```
> /Room\.aspx\?RT=(\d+)/.exec('/Rate.aspx#/HotelMobileBooking/Room.aspx?RT=47')[1]
'47'
```

If you want to access the value in the *current* URL, use `location.hash` to access the `#...` part of the url.

Comment: Copied from the nodejs shell. Pretty much standard syntax to show that something was executed in an interactive interpreter (even though python's `>>> ` is more obvious).

Comment: Pardon me for asking i want to know the steps to do when the page first loads for Room.aspx because i am just a beginner at jquery

Comment: @user1381205. It has nothing to do with `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

no need to use a regular expression. If `RT` is the only parameter in your querystring just use `split()`

```
url = ".../Rate.aspx#/HotelMobileBooking/Room.aspx?RT=47";
url.split("?RT=")[1]; //47
```

Answer (score 0):

This question tells you how to retrieve a query string value using jQuery: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Assuming that the URL you posted is the URL of the page that you are on...